# getting error in fromGroup earlier it was working fine but now showing error

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(uploadForm.organization)">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">
        <h6 class="text-success">Contact Email</h6>
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></div>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='organization.ContactEmail' placeholder="Contact Email" />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

> **OrgnizationFormComponent.html:18 ERROR Error:**
>         **ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using**
>         **formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.**  **Example:**
>
> ```
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
> ```
>
> In your class:
>
> `this.myGroup = new FormGroup({   firstName: new FormControl() });`
>
> Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate
>   that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
>   <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
> </div>
> ```

Comment: ``ngModel``in reactive forms is deprecated . use ``FormControlName``

Answer (score 0):

You should use form for the `ngSubmit`.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitFunction()">
...
</form>
```

See the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#listening-for-form-submission) API.

Comment: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use event submit on FormGroup as ReactiveForm

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

...

Link: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#saving-form-data